# How can I count the number of accesses/queries to database through Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using the Mongoid in a Rails project. To improve the performance of large queries, I'm using the [includes method](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid%2FCriteria%3Aincludes) to eager load the relationships.

I would like to know if there is an easy way to count the real number of queries performed by a block of code so that I can check if my `includes` really reduced the number of DB accesses as expected. Something like:

```rb
# It will perform a large query to gather data from companies and their relationships
count = Mongoid.count_queries do
  Company.to_csv
end

puts count # Number of DB access
```

I want to use this feature to add Rspec tests to prove that my query remains efficient after changes (e.g; when adding data from a new relationship). In python's Django framework, for instance, one may use the [assertNumQueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertNumQueries) method to this end.

Answer (score 4):

I just implemented this feature to count mongo queries in my rspec suite in a small module using mongo [Command Monitoring](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-monitoring/#command-monitoring).

It can be used like this:

```rb
expect { code }.to change { finds("users") }.by(3)
expect { code }.to change { updates("contents") }.by(1)
expect { code }.not_to change { inserts }
```

Or:

```rb
MongoSpy.flush
# ..code..
expect(MongoSpy.queries).to match(
  "find" => { "users" => 1, "contents" => 1 },
  "update" => { "users" => 1 }
)
```

Here is the Gist (ready to copy) for the last up-to-date version: https://gist.github.com/jarthod/ab712e8a31798799841c5677cea3d1a0

And here is the current version:

```rb
module MongoSpy
  module Helpers
    %w(find delete insert update).each do |op|
      define_method(op.pluralize) { |ns = nil|
        ns ? MongoSpy.queries[op][ns] : MongoSpy.queries[op].values.sum
      }
    end
  end

  class << self
    def queries
      @queries ||= Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(0) }
    end

    def flush
      @queries = nil
    end

    def started(event)
      op = event.command.keys.first # find, update, delete, createIndexes, etc.
      ns = event.command[op] # collection name
      return unless ns.is_a?(String)
      queries[op][ns] += 1
    end

    def succeeded(_); end
    def failed(_); end
  end
end

Mongo::Monitoring::Global.subscribe(Mongo::Monitoring::COMMAND, MongoSpy)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include MongoSpy::Helpers
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Checking on r[ubygems.org](http://ubygems.org) didn't yield anything that seems to do what you want.
You might be better off looking into app performance tools like [New Relic](https://newrelic.com/), [Scout](https://scoutapm.com/), or [DataDog](https://www.datadoghq.com/). You may be able to get some out of the gate benchmarking specs with

https://github.com/piotrmurach/rspec-benchmark

Comment: Thanks for answering. Measure the performance test is an interesting alternative, although it is not exactly what I need now. Performance tests are susceptible to its environment, e.g.; the CI container runs slower than my local machine, which may break tests. Moreover, N+1 problems get worse when the N is large, which is hard/expensive to check trhough unit tests as you have to create a large sample of entries in the database.

Comment: @ArthurDelEsposte I understand your challenges but building up sample test data might be better than nothing. I know for fact that both pghero and New Relic are able to identify n+1 and slow queries. I am fairly sure New Relic supports MongoDB.
I might suggest looking at the source code for [pghero](https://github.com/ankane/pghero) for ideas on how you might build your own tool for this.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is command monitoring. With Mongoid and the Ruby Driver, you can create a custom command monitoring class that you can use to subscribe to all commands made to the server.

I've adapted this from the [Command Monitoring Guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-monitoring/#command-monitoring) for the Mongo Ruby Driver.

For this particular example, make sure that your Rails app has the log level set to debug. You can read more about the Rails logger [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#what-is-the-logger-questionmark).

The first thing you want to do is define a subscriber class. This is the class that tells your application what to do when the `Mongo::Client` performs commands against the database. Here is the example class from the documentation:

```
class CommandLogSubscriber
  include Mongo::Loggable

  # called when a command is started
  def started(event)
    log_debug("#{prefix(event)} | STARTED | #{format_command(event.command)}")
  end

  # called when a command finishes successfully
  def succeeded(event)
    log_debug("#{prefix(event)} | SUCCEEDED | #{event.duration}s")
  end

  # called when a command terminates with a failure
  def failed(event)
    log_debug("#{prefix(event)} | FAILED | #{event.message} | #{event.duration}s")
  end

  private

  def logger
    Mongo::Logger.logger
  end

  def format_command(args)
    begin
      args.inspect
    rescue Exception
      '<Unable to inspect arguments>'
    end
  end

  def format_message(message)
    format("COMMAND | %s".freeze, message)
  end

  def prefix(event)
    "#{event.address.to_s} | #{event.database_name}.#{event.command_name}"
  end
end
```

(Make sure this class is auto-loaded in your Rails application.)

Next, you want to attach this subscriber to the client you use to perform commands.

```
subscriber = CommandLogSubscriber.new

Mongo::Monitoring::Global.subscribe(Mongo::Monitoring::COMMAND, subscriber)

# This is the name of the default client, but it's possible you've defined
#   a client with a custom name in config/mongoid.yml
client = Mongoid::Clients.from_name('default')
client.subscribe( Mongo::Monitoring::COMMAND, subscriber)
```

Now, when Mongoid executes any commands against the database, those commands will be logged to your console.

```
# For example, if you have a model called Book
Book.create(title: "Narnia")
# => D, [2020-03-27T10:29:07.426209 #43656] DEBUG -- : COMMAND | localhost:27017 | mongoid_test_development.insert | STARTED | {"insert"=>"books", "ordered"=>true, "documents"=>[{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5e7e0db3f8f498aa88b26e5d'), "title"=>"Narnia", "updated_at"=>2020-03-27 14:29:07.42239 UTC, "created_at"=>2020-03-27 14:29:07.42239 UTC}], "lsid"=>{"id"=><BSON::Binary:0x10600 type=uuid data=0xfff8a93b6c964acb...>}}
# => ...
```

You can modify the `CommandLogSubscriber` class to do something other than logging (such as incrementing a global counter).